# Is there any solution for multiple checkbox selection using for loop?

Tags: java, selenium

I am using a for-loop for selecting multiple checkboxes. It selects the 
checkboxes, but if I select index value 1 then I run the code, it selects 1 value but jumps 2 value and selects 3 checkboxes.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//li[@class='px-2']")
List <WebElement> listofitems;
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    listofitems.get(i).click();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Is `i`supposed to start at 0 and loop to `i<5` instead of `i<=5` ?

Comment: When you say jumps value 2, does the the i value changing from 1 to 3 directly skipping 2?

Comment: It may jump due one of your `li` missing the class `px-2`. Check the size of the List `listofitems`, then check how many `li` has `px-2`.

Comment: Put a sleep of maybe 50ms after the click and see if that helps. My guess is that the page needs a chance to respond to the first click and multiple clicks are happening too fast and it can't keep up so some clicks are lost.

Comment: @supputuri Yes, it Skips Second value and Selects third value directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below code

for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
    listofitems.get(i).click();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to click multiple checkbox. Then try iterating between the elements and perform the click option. If you have any text in your element identifier then use something like this

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//li[@class='px-2']"));

        foreach(WebElement chkBox in checkboxes)
        {
            if(chkBox.Text.Contains("checkBoxName"))
            {
                chkBox.Click();
            }
        }`
```

else if you want to click all the checkbox, then simply use without the if condition

```
foreach(WebElement chkBox in checkboxes)
{
   chkBox.Click();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't,t work. It gives error on Text. contains                                  
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//li[@class='px-2']"));

        foreach(WebElement chkBox in checkboxes)
        {
            if(chkBox.Text.Contains("checkBoxName"))
            {
                chkBox.Click();
            }
        }